# Google Knowledge Graph API `articleBody` field missing from `detailedDescription`

Tags: google-api, google-knowledge-graph

Following the sample request for Taylor Swift shown [here](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/), I get the following response which does not match the response shown on the site. Moreover, I'm interested in the `articleBody` of the `detailedDescription` field which is not being returned the same way. Has there been an update to the API that was not reflected in the documentation? Is there a way to request the `articleBody` via the [Python API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/kgsearch/v1/python/latest/kgsearch_v1.entities.html)?

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
    "goog": "http://schema.googleapis.com/",
    "EntitySearchResult": "goog:EntitySearchResult",
    "detailedDescription": "goog:detailedDescription",
    "resultScore": "goog:resultScore",
    "kg": "http://g.co/kg"
  },
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "itemListElement": [
    {
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/m/0dl567",
        "name": "Taylor Swift",
        "@type": [
          "Thing",
          "Person"
        ],
        "description": "American singer",
        "image": {
          "contentUrl": "http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcST848UJ0u31E6aoQfb2nnKZFyad7rwNF0ZLOCACGpu4jnboEzV",
          "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begin_Again_(Taylor_Swift_song)"
        },
        "url": "http://taylorswift.com/"
      },
      "resultScore": 1237.141968
    }
  ]
}
```